# Creating test in NeoLoad from WSDL with http authentication

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, performance-testing, neoload

I am creating a performancetest in the tool NeoLoad for several webservices.
You can insert a soap request in your test.
After hitting this option in the menu a window opens in which you have to enter a wsdl(-location) or choose for creating everything manual.
When i enter the WSDL location an error is given (http status code 401).
When i open the same location in a webbrowser i am asked for login credentials.
However in NeoLoad i don't get this question.
I tried adding userid and pasword to the location (http://user:pwd@serv.com/test?wsdl) but then the 401 error was given for the xsd's mentioned in the wsdl.
Has anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neotys fixed this problem in NeoLoad 5.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a workaround: open the WSDL with your browser, download it with its related files (includes...) and pick the file on the disk from NeoLoad.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i added the WSDL in SoapUI and created thespecific call in there.
In SoapUI in have to sett user and password on a few places.
Then i change the proxy used bij SoapUI tot localhost:8090 (NeoLoad).
I press the records button in NeoLOad, hit play in SoapUI and after getting and awnser in SoapUI i stop the recording in NeoLoad.